# Provide hint to IntelliSense that a partial class should not be modified

Tags: c#, code-generation, intellisense

As of lately I'm using quite some code generation, usually in combination with partial classes. Basically the setup is as follows:

- Partial class containing generated code. Some of this code will call partial methods. The code is re-generated a lot of time. The code generator is in some cases a custom tool.
- Partial methods are manually implemented in a separate file.

The problem is that when I'm using Intellisense features like "generate method", they are for some reason generated in the file containing the generated code. Obviously I don't want that.

My question is: Is it possible to generate some hint that tells Intellisense it shouldn't touch certain 'cs' files (but instead the other partial class)?

---

**Update**

In retrospect I should have noted that I'm using a custom tool to generate the code. It's not a EF or a simple transformation; there's quite a bit of logic involved in the code generation. Also, it generates a complete namespace and class structure with partial classes. The 'root namespace' is found by extracting it from the `csproj` file and then using the folder structure to figure out the absolute namespace (it's similar to how Linq2sql does this).

The answer suggested by xanatos (thanks!) works: intellisense sorts its operation on the name, then alphabetically sorts on the name and then picks the first item in the list. This means that you can generate a `zzzz.foo.cs` which (albeit a bit ugly) will work just fine. I've just ran some experiments and found out that the feature `find all references` returns the order that VS appears to use. As it turns out, it works like this:

Say you have a custom tool that works on the filename `foo.bar` and transforms it into `foo.cs`. The custom tool will generate the content as string and pass it back to Visual studio (that's just how custom tools work...). The result will be in a file called `foo.cs`.

Now, I was quite surprised to found that Intellisense does *not* sort it as `foo.cs` but rather as `foo.bar\foo.cs`. In other words: regardless of how you name the 'cs' output in your custom tool, you have to rename the base file `foo.bar` to something like `zoo.bar`.

While that might be a workaround, I'm hesistant to accept it as the answer, because I would have to give files in my project strange names (names have meaning...). Also, some of my custom tools have dependencies on their filenames, so that will also get broken...

Therefore, I'm still open for suggestions on how to fix this properly.

Answer (score 4):

From a simple test I've done in VS2013, it seems that Visual Studio 2013 adds the method to the "first" file he finds in the Solution Explorer. So you could simply add a `.something.cs` to your file-name, like `MyClass.generated.cs` vs `MyClass.cs`. Be aware that the VS2013 seems to be using the "full path", with path ordering based on name. So:

> Z\MyClass.cs

comes after

> MyClass.generated.cs

(and Intellisense will put code in `MyClass.generated.cs`) even while in the Solution Explorer all the folders are ordered first.

Full example:

> A\MyClass.gen3.cs
>
> MyClass.gen2.cs
>
> Z\MyClass.gen1.cs

This should be the order as "seen" by the Intellisense, so it will put the new classes in `A\MyClass.gen3.cs`.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that it uses the full path.... I was already afraid of that: some of my generators (f.ex. my lexer/parser code generator) produces complete (child namespace) class hierarchies in a single, generated file. Basically that means that no matter how I name it, it will generate the code in the wrong file.

Comment: @atlaste There is always the `z.z.z.zenerated.cs` file :-)

Comment: Yes I also thought about that - problem is that that solution doesn't work if it orders the current folder 'above' the subfolders. I'll have to try that though.

Comment: @atlaste Then put it in the z\z.z.z.zenerated.cs folder :-)

Comment: xanatos, Yea well, that's actually tricky with custom tools; you just return the string and VS generates the file for you. Also, manually putting it into a child folder is tricky, because I determine the namespace from the folder relative to the csproj file. I can of course hack around both, but I'd rather not. From your 'full example' the z.z solution might work - but that would mean renaming the file before firing the custom tool of course.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about the EF, I always change the template file (.tt) so the filename of the auto-generated file is [classname].model.cs. This means my partial file, which by convention is called [classname].cs is alphabetically first and always seems to get picked for auto-generation.

All you have to do is find/replace all the:

```
fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
```

With:

```
fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".model.cs");
```

There should be 3.

This has other benefits like auto-generated files are clearly marked in the filename.

I still have no idea why they didn't do this in the first place.

If you're not talking about the EF, the same trick of using the filename to order them should work.